# CORS during development without Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: django, cors

The server answer with a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` value set for the production. Is there a way to be permissive when the requests come from my development server ? Is there a Django setting to disable the cross-origin check when `DEBUG=True` for example ?

I can't modify the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. The request is made with jquery ajax function.

EDIT:

I've installed https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers with `pip install django-cors-headers`, added the following in my `settings.py`

```
if DEBUG:
    INSTALLED_APPS += ('corsheaders', )

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = DEBUG
```

And put the middleware :

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
...
}
```

But I still get the error :

*Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at _request_url_. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).*

If I inspect the response header, I don't see any `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` parameter.

Comment: Can you please add your Django version to the question?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Install middleware: https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers

In django settings.py add following setting:

`DEBUG=True`

`CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = DEBUG`

(if `DEBUG` is true `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` will be added to headers in response)

Answer (score 4):

To add CORS headers to your response, install this to your django project:

https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers

Since you want to connect from local, you cannot whitelist a particular host alone.

To enable CORS only when you have `DEBUG=True`, you can add corsheaders to your installed apps only when Debug is True:

```
if DEBUG is True:
     INSTALLED_APPS += ('corsheaders', )
```