# Cross-Origin Request Blocked issue using Angular 4 and Django

Tags: django, angular

I have two applications on two machine.

1. Backend app using Django (example 123.431.234.123:8080)
2. Frontend app using Angular (example 123.431.234.124:4200)

Now I am trying to post request from angular

```html
this.http.post<any>('http://123.431.234.123:8080/login/', { username: username, password: password })
```

I am getting error on browser:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://123.431.234.123:8080/login/. (Reason: CORS header âAccess-Control-Allow-Originâ missing).

When I am trying with curl command on my ubuntu machine, I am able to get the response successfully.

```html
curl -d  '{"username":"admin" ,"password":"carpediem"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"  http://123.431.234.123:8080/login/
```

I tried to follow many links and also setup my django setting.py file as

[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40760813/cors-during-development-without-access-control-allow-origin?rq=1)

[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38482059/enabling-cors-cross-origin-request-in-django)

and did step by step configuration as below

`pip install django-cors-headers`
Adds to installed apps

INSTALLED_APPS = (

```
...
'corsheaders',
...
```

)
Add  MIDDLEWARE

MIDDLEWARE = [

```
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
...
```

]

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL=True
```

After all changes, I am still facing the same issue. It might be duplicate question, But Please help me to solve it.

I am using Mozila firefox, Do I need to do any changes in browser or any other settings?

Comment: Are you trying to use API locally?

Comment: No, its in different machine.

Answer (score 0):

This is due by the browser security. The browser does not allow access to the IP of your backend by another IP like *127.0.0.1* (localhost)

If you're using Google Chrome, try [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi).